# To add common files in a common folder for all the adapters in MF8

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I am working on MF8 java adapters. 
Is there a common server folder to have the common java files as in MF7?

Here each adapter is taken as a maven project. It's good that we can deploy then together by defining them as modules under a single `pom.xml`.

```
<modules>
    <module>Adapter1</module>
    <module>Adapter2</module>
</modules>
```

Still, to have the common files. Any options to place them in a common folder?
Packaging them as a jar becoming painful while debugging. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can group adapter Maven projects in a parent Maven project. That way you can specify your shared dependencies in the pom.xml of the parent Maven project and those will be added to all child Maven projects when you're building them. See: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/#grouping-adapters-in-a-single-maven-project

Comment: My shared dependencies are my services code(java),You mean to say to package it as a jar and add in parent pom.xml?

Comment: Those can still be used via dependencies, but it'll need to be packaged first, yes.